# How to retrieve groups of n documents from cursor (collection)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm looking for a way to retrieve in my template groups of 3 documents of the collection "Questions" which have almost 50 documents.   After the first 3 docs (questions) shown in the template the user should decide (pushing a button) if he wants to retrieve the next 3 documents or just finish.

I haven't found a way to load the questions from 3 to 3.  This is my code:

collections.js:

```
Questions = new Mongo.Collection("questions");
```

myapp.js:

```
var lastQ=0
Template.questions.helpers ({
  getGroupQuestions: function(){
    //Ideally if I only query one time the entire collection, and store in local var
    var listOfQuest = Questions.find({$and: [ {qNumber: {$nin: answeredQ}}, {qNumber:{$gt:lastQ}}]}, {sort:{qNumber:1}}); 

    lastQ = lastQ + 3;
    return {"Obj1":listOfQuest.fetch()[0], "Obj2":listOfQuest.fetch()[1], "Obj3":listOfQuest.fetch()[2]};  //This is not working, the returned object cant be read in template
  }
});
```

myapp.html:

```
<template name="questions">
  <h4> Tell us a little about yourself: </h4>
  <form class="js-add-answers" id="add-answers">
    {{#each getGroupQuestions}}
      <label for="{{qNumber}}">{{qDescription}}</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="{{qNumber}}" placeholder="{{qHints}}"/>
      <p></p>
    {{/each}}
    <button class="btn btn-warning js-join-event">Save and Join</button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning js-load-more">Save and load more Q</button>        
   </form> 
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i see from you question, all I can tell is you just need to use **skip** and **limit** in the function while getting documents. Ideally you should remove "insecure" and "auto-publish" package first and use PUB/SUB technique in the code.

Below is the code that you can use to get your desired result.

At server end you should publish the code with skip count.

**PROJECT/server/publish.js**

```
Meteor.publish('getGroupQuestions', function(skipcount){
    return Questions.find(
                          {$and: [ {qNumber : {$nin: answeredQ}},
                                   {sort : {qNumber:1}}
                          },{limit : 3, skip : skipCount}
         });
});
```

At Client side declare below peice of code as session variable to skip number of records accordingly by 3;

**client/template/myapp.js**

```
 Session.setDefault('skip', 0);
 Deps.autorun(function(){
     Meteor.subscribe('getGroupQuestions', Session.get('skip'));
 });

 Template.questions.events ({
    "submit .load-more" : function() {
        Session.set(Session.get('skip') + 3)
    }
 });
```

In myapp.html, you have to make a small change and name the button as below;

**client/template/myapp.html**

```
<button name="load-more" class="btn btn-warning js-load-more">Save and load more Q</button>
```

---

> Explanation of flow

---

1. Initially when the page loads , it will give you top 3 results as per logic.
2. When the user clicks the button for *load more*, the template event gets invoked and the session is set with new value of "skip" (incremented by 3).
3. Due to Meteor re-activity and asynchronous behavior, the publishing container will auto-update the collection with next 3 questions by firing the same query again but with new skip counter in the session. 
   The page won't even refresh and you shall se the new group of questions.

Comment: Thank you!  Your code looks pretty clean....  Just a doubt:  Should I call the result in my template through a helper like that:  
`template.questions.helpers({ threeQuest: function() { return Questions.find()}});`
I wonder if it's right since I have another subscription to Questions in other template which require to load the whole collection.

Comment: The scope of subscription remains intact within the template only. Make subscriptions on specific templates separately, you will feel faster rendering. So, Dear friend, no matter how many places you are using the subcription, the render in template helper depends on condition you pass in find method. I gave you the code to find exact three fresh questions. You can copy paste it in template helper as well. No harm shall be done. Other template subscription is unharmed anyways. Thank you so much.

Comment: Ok.  Just one more question (Be patient with this newbie please =S ): How I do my subscription specific to my template?  Should I put the 'sub' inside the template helper?   Already I put my subscription inside of Meteor.isClient and create a helper like mentioned above, but the Questions.find query in helper are retrieving all the records from collection and not only the 3 required.   I think the problem its caused by my other subscription which is bringing all the records from 'Questions' to minimongodb.  That subscription its required too for another template.

Comment: What I finally did was to put the query you provide me directly in helper and delete the pub/sub since I had a broader subscription to 'Questions'.  It is working now.  Thanks a lot Ankur!

Comment: Thank you so much! You are too kind, Just become master of meteor and help others as well. World need us!